# Adding data to the plist dynamically and populating the tableview cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I am developing an application where i have created the plist, and i am adding data to it..but what is happening is that everytime the data is overwritten and the previous data is lost. I mean suppose i add one name called rocky, next time when i add rock, rocky gets overwritten with rock, but what i want is my plist should contain both rocky and rock and so on...I am adding the data in plist by user entry....

here is my code below..

```
-(IBAction) myplist:(id) sender//the data is saved in a plist by clicking on this button
{
NSLog(@"mylist  Clicked");    

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array addObject:searchLabel.text];

   // get paths from root direcory

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// get documents path

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// get the path to our Data/plist file

NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];



// This writes the array to a plist file. If this file does not already exist, it creates a new one.

   [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will serve your purpose with a slight modification to your code.

```
NSLog(@"mylist  Clicked");    
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


// get paths from root direcory

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// get documents path

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// get the path to our Data/plist file

NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];


//This copies objects of plist to array if there is one
[array addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]];
[array addObject:searchLabel.text];
// This writes the array to a plist file. If this file does not already exist, it creates a new one.

[array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
```

Comment: thank you sony it worked..and it was exactly what i wanted...but now..one more problem it works on simulator..but how to make it run on the device..please help me out.

Comment: Hi sony,i want to ask one more thing,what i should if i want to add only 3 values in the plist and then later if the user adds more then i t will be overwritten...how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a sequence to store data to pList.

1., retrieve old data from pList into a NSMutableDictionary/NSMutableArray

2., add a new record into the NSMutableDictionary/NSMutableArray

3., write to file

Comment: thanks Vanya..for your reply..can u please let me what changes should i make in my previous code so that i will get wat i want..because i am new to it.....

Comment: hi vanya...i tried..sonys solution and it works fine..in simulator..i want to know what changes we should make so that it can be run on iphone device also..

Comment: no changes are needed, it should work on simulator and device as well

Comment: can u tell me how u change the path

Answer (score 0):

You cant append data to Plist. Since you are doing writeToFile each time , the plist file gets re-written. So the data u stored initially will not be there in it. The only other way to achieve wat u desire is to retrieve the array of data from the plist. Then add ur new data object to the array. Write the plist file to disk again with the new appended array.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks booleanBoy for your reply..if u tell me what changes i should make in my above code,would be better,because ,i am new ot it..